# Replace ASP .NET Eval when data binding with type-safe mechanism

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm looking forward to refactor some pieces of application and there are many lines of code that look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Employee.LAST_NAME")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Employee.FIRST_NAME")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

When refactoring property names (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME) Visual Studio doesn't of course find these references to properties in Eval. So now, when I'm refactoring would like to replace it with something type-safe + something that can be spotted during compile time, just in case in the future I need to refactor once again. Is there any way to replace Eval with better mechanism?

Comment: In the next version of Visual Studio, you can do strongly typed data binding, http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/whitepapers/whats-new#_Toc318097385

Comment: @grahammendick: You just made my day!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Eval` is evil (why is a long story), use `((Employee)Container.DataItem).LAST_NAME` and `((Employee)Container.DataItem).FIRST_NAME` instead - it's faster, type safe, refactor friendly, avoids reflection, etc...

Comment: even better is to use the asp.net 4.5 strongly type data binding, just like graham mendick referred